# Getting currency data using OAuth2 with the private key API

Tags: yahoo-oauth

My developer is not sure how he would use OAuth2 in order to access currency data from PHP script using the Yahoo private key API and the Yahoo Query language (YQL).

He doesn't find a complete documentation to do so on in the Yahoo developer account. If somebody has any experience with that, could you provide a documentation or an example code how to use OAuth2 with the private key Yahoo API?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo's OAuth2 guide is located here: [Yahoo OAuth 2.0 Guide](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/)

The "[Explicit Grant Flow](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/flows_authcode/)" and "[Implicit Grant Flow](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/flows_implicitgrant/)" sections (depending on your needs) specify the sequence of steps needed to get an access token.  The "[Making API Requests](https://developer.yahoo.com/oauth2/guide/apirequests/)" section provides detail on how to include the access token in API requests to Yahoo's web services.

Hope this helps.

-Igor